# Custom UIPopoverController (UIPopoverBackgroundView) in iOS 4.x

Tags: ipad, ios4, uipopovercontroller

I customize `UIPopoverController` through create custom `UIPopoverBackgroundView` class
It works good in iOS 5+
But in iOS 4.x `UIPopoverController` don't has property `popoverBackgroundViewClass`

How I can apply `popoverBackgroundViewClass` and customize `UIPopoverController` in iOS 4.x?

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't. Because `UIPopoverBackgroundView` is only available [after](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverBackgroundView_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIPopoverBackgroundView) iOS 5.0.